# occurrence of tuples in column duplicates

Tags: python, csv

This code, extracted from another question, works perfectly. It counts the occurrences of each row in a column and output a csv file.

I would like it to not remove duplicates in my output file

input file example are word tags

```
WP,VBZ
VBZ,PRP
PRP,VB
VB,PRP
WP,VBZ
VBZ,PRP
```

.

```
def filtrar():

files3= glob.glob('C:/Users/Sebastian/Desktop/aristas/*.csv')
for path in files3:
    dirname, filename = os.path.split(path)
    with open('C:/Users/Sebastian/Desktop/aristas/%s' %filename) as csvfile:
        occurrence = Counter(tuple(row[0:2]) for row in csv.reader(csvfile))
    with open('C:/Users/Sebastian/Desktop/aristasPeso/%s' 
    %filename,'w',newline='') as output2:
        writer = csv.writer(output2)
        for (dest, src), cnt in occurrence.items():
            writer.writerow([dest,src,cnt])
```

I want this output for example:

```
WP,VBZ,2
VBZ,PRP,1
PRP,VB,1
VB,PRP,1
WP,VBZ,2
VBZ,PRP,2
```

not like

```
WP,VBZ,2
VBZ,PRP,2
PRP,VB,1
VB,PRP,1
```

Comment: Can you show the input data? For the sake of reproduce-ability. Also have you tried simply removing the Counter, which is obviously making each element it contains unique, in terms of the key.

Comment: input data is just rows of tuples like:

[[WP,VBZ],
,[VBZ,PRP]
,[PRP,VB]
,[VB,PRP]]
.......
but counter makes  "occurrance" works?, if counter makes every element unique then is a problem :(

Comment: you are trying to read all rows from the `word.csv` file, form the 2nd and 3rd column value to a tuple, then count all of them. The Counter will count duplicated tuple, and increase the count.

Comment: sorry, edited the actual working (but not what I want) code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need save all rows data first, and based on the Counter, get the count, then form the row data and the count to be a list, write into csv file :

```
import csv
from collections import Counter
with open('words.csv') as csvfile:    
    source_data = [tuple(row[0:2]) for row in csv.reader(csvfile)] #get all rows and save it
    occurrence = Counter(source_data) #count the rows occurrence
with open('occurence.csv','wb') as output2:
    writer = csv.writer(output2)
    for dest_src in source_data: #loop over the all source rows, and get the rows occurrence, and write into file
        writer.writerow(list(dest_src)+[occurrence[dest_src]])
```

`occurence.csv` file will be:

```
WP,VBZ,2
VBZ,PRP,2
PRP,VB,1
VB,PRP,1
WP,VBZ,2
VBZ,PRP,2
```

Comment: im getting
File "C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\Nodos-Vertices.py", line 26, in filtrar
    writer.writerow(dest_src_lst+[cnt])
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

is it because the "wb"? when you open

edit: it was because the wb, changed to "w"

Comment: works perfect now!! and its like way faster than before it was 1.x second , now its like 0,05 sec!! thanks again! :D

Comment: @SebastianCánepa cheers.  if it is helpful, please don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer :)

Comment: Change the 'wb' to 'w' mode in python 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

Like said, `Counter` will keep track of unique instances of counted objects. This solution appends each of your rows to a separate array `data` and then prints it all into a file with the count collect from `Counter` object for that entry:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

data = []
occurence = Counter()
with open('words.csv') as f:
    next(f)  # skip header
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        occurence.update([tuple(row)])
        data.append(row[0:2])

with open('occurrence.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['Destination', 'Source', 'Counts'])
    for dest,src in data:
        writer.writerow([dest, src, occurence[(dest,src)]])
```

Comment: yes I see what I was doing in this line "for (dest,src) in data:" , I was doing for in occurrence

Comment: I left it there by accident ;) it's redundant here, works just fine without the brackets! It's a neat trick for extracting tuples from the Counter- checked it just now, without the brackets wouldn't work.